# How do you disable XON/OFF flow control?

Tags: command-line, stty

I issued a `stty -ixon` command which enables XON/XOFF flow control.

There is a `stty -ixoff` command but that enables the "sending of start/stop characters".

So once XON/XOFF flow control is enabled, how do you disable it? Similarly, how do you disable "sending of start/stop characters?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`stty -ixon` disables XON/XOFF output control; `stty ixon` enables it. In general, [`stty -flag`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) disables the corresponding [`termios`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) flag, `stty flag` enables it.