# Vim freezes after Ctrl-S

Tags: vim

I have been using `neovim` for a long time and I have been using `Ctrl + s` to save and `Ctrl + q` to quit.

```
nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a

nmap <c-q> :q<CR>
imap <c-q> <Esc>:q<CR>
```

Due to the unexpected behavior of `nvim` with `coc` I switched to `vim`. It's using the same configuration but `Ctrl + s` freezes the editor and `Ctrl + q` is required to unfreeze it. I'm using `Simple Terminal` and it does not freeze for `Ctrl + s`.

```
NVIM v0.4.2
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1
```

Comment: Typo in first sentence I think?

Comment: Also, there is no question here.  But your terminal is intercepting the ctrl q and ctrl s before vim ever sees them.

Comment: @Wildcard Use your common sense

Comment: @s1n7ax Proofread your posts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is probably your terminal. It looks like it is configured to have flow control enabled. Disable it.

Flow control was used in the old days, when things were slow enough that we could pause a scrolling screen. ctrl-s is pause/scroll-lock, ctrl-q is continue.

Comment: "I'm sorry Dave I'm afraid I can't do that" "Why not, HAL?" "Because you pressed CTRL-S".

Comment: Use `stty -ixon` to disable flow control. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515257/43878